# Android:Passing ArrayList of BasicNameValuePairs with intent to another Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, serialization, arraylist

I have to send an `ArrayList` of `BasicNameValuePair`s to another Activity in my Android app. First it did not allow me to do this, saying `BasicNameValuePair` is not serializable.

So after reading a few other answers, I followed their recommendations made my own class called `SerializedNameValuePair` which implements serializable, and thought of passing an `ArrayList` of this.

```
public class SerializedNameValuePair implements Serializable, NameValuePair{

    private BasicNameValuePair nvp;

    public SerializedNameValuePair(String name, String value){
        nvp=new BasicNameValuePair(name, value);

    }

     @Override
        public String getName() {
            return nvp.getName();
        }

        @Override
        public String getValue() {
            return nvp.getValue();
        }

        // serialization support

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
            out.writeChars(nvp.getName());
            out.writeChars(nvp.getValue());
        }

        private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
            nvp = new BasicNameValuePair(in.readUTF(), in.readUTF());
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private void readObjectNoData() throws ObjectStreamException {
            // nothing to do
        }

}
```

Then i make an `ArrayList` of this and try passing it in an `Intent`.

`places` is declared as a variable of `ShipmentFindingActivity` itself.

```
ArrayList <SerializedNameValuePair>places;
```

In the `postExecute` of an `AsyncTask` I initialize it.

```
places=new ArrayList<SerializedNameValuePair>();
```

Then I populate the `ArrayList` in a for loop.

```
SerializedNameValuePair nvp=new SerializedNameValuePair(eventname, placename);
places.add(nvp);
```

There is a button that has it's visibility set to invisible first. After the `postExecute` executes, it becomes visible and it's `onClick` is `openMap`.

```
public void openMap(View view){
    System.out.println("Map View Button Pressed");

    Intent intent=new Intent(context, MapViewingActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("places", places);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Here the app crashes when i click on the button. I am receiving the intent in `MapViewingActivity` like this:

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
nameValuePairs=(ArrayList<SerializedNameValuePair>) intent.getSerializableExtra("nvp");
```

When the app crashes this is what I get in LogCat:

```
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733): Process: com.example.tradeapp, PID: 2733
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tradeapp/com.example.tradeapp.MapViewingActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object (name = com.example.tradeapp.SerializedNameValuePair)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object (name = com.example.tradeapp.SerializedNameValuePair)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2215)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2064)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2343)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1703)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2034)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2314)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(Bundle.java:1295)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at android.content.Intent.getSerializableExtra(Intent.java:4694)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at com.example.tradeapp.MapViewingActivity.onCreate(MapViewingActivity.java:38)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     ... 11 more
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733): Caused by: java.io.EOFException
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at libcore.io.Streams.readFully(Streams.java:83)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:99)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at java.io.DataInputStream.decodeUTF(DataInputStream.java:178)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at java.io.DataInputStream.decodeUTF(DataInputStream.java:173)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:169)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:2113)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at com.example.tradeapp.SerializedNameValuePair.readObject(SerializedNameValuePair.java:41)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1332)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2213)
06-04 06:39:13.546: E/AndroidRuntime(2733):     ... 23 more
```

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: You can try Parcelable

Comment: @Lollipop Well I have no idea what that is, I'll look it up and try it out.

Comment: You are passing using key `places` but retrieving using `nvp`. Why?

Comment: @kartik look this http://derekknox.com/daklab/2012/09/05/quick-tip-android-parcelable-example-with-arraylist/ Parcellable is faster than serializable Ref this http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/

Comment: @Lollipop umm... I've implemented parcelable and added all the required methods into a class called ParcelableNVParray. Following derekknox's quide, the class has a constructor that takes in a Parcel to initialize the data. How do i store my ArrayList into this Parcel now??

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that since the class `BasicNameValuePair` itself is not `Serializable`, putting it in another class that is `Serializable` or `Parcelable` or anything of that sort leads to the same error, I tried making a class `SerializedNameValuePair` that implemented `Serializable` and had a `BasicNameValuePair`, then made an `ArrayList` of `SerializedNameValuePair`, then stored that `ArrayList` in an object whose class implemented `Parcelable`. Still no result, it all came down to `BasicNameValuePair` is not `Serializable`. So why use `BasicNameValuePair` at all? I just made a simple class called `StringPair` that implemented `Serializable` and then I was easily able to pass the `ArrayList` of `StringPair` in an `Intent`. This seems like the simplest, cleanest method to me.

Here is my class:

```
public class StringPair implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public String first;
    public String second;
    public StringPair(String first, String second){
        this.first=first;
        this.second=second;
    }

}
```

And I send an `Intent` like this:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(context, MapViewingActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("places", (Serializable)places);
startActivity(intent);
```

Where `places` is:

```
ArrayList<StringPair>places=new ArrayList<StringPair>();
```

I receive the `Intent` again like this:

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
ArrayList<StringPair >nameValuePairs=(ArrayList<StringPair >)intent.getSerializableExtra("places");
```

This code worked perfectly for me and it's extremely simple.

Some may argue that `Parcelable` is alot faster than `Serializable`, but according to the benchmarks provided in http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/ , there is a difference of few miliseconds between the two when the contents of the bundle are read/written 1000 times. In my app I know that my `ArrayList` will not contain more than 10 elements so I went ahead with `Serializable` knowing it would not make a difference in speed, and will reduce complexity.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create  a customClass that implement Parcebale, you can see this issue it work fine 
[Create intent with parcebale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2141166/2764682)